# Burninate [age] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[age](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age) (9 questions) looks like a meta tag, it doesn't help categorize questions. And [age is largely irrelevant](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/age-appropriateness-and-its-irrelevance) anyway.

I think [age-appropriate](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-appropriate) (86 questions) is less bad, since we understand what's *really* being asked (i.e. substitute age for maturity or some other factor).

Should [age](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age) be burninated? Maybe synonymed to [age-appropriate](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-appropriate)? There are 2 questions with no other tags besides [age](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age).

Answer (score 2):

I agree - for the questions currently using the [age](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age) tag it serves no purpose.

I will remove it. I think the [age-appropriate](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-appropriate) tag is fine.